# Where is configure settings for texstudio?

Tags: ubuntu, tex

I installed `texlive`, then I installed `texstudio`, but the `texstudio` GUI has no `configure settings`, as:[image: texstudio interface]
And when I'm trying to compile a tex project which was successfully compiled on windows, it gives the error:

```
File `totpages.sty' not found. \RequirePackage
```

I suspect if it's because I have not set the paths in configure settings, can someone help me? Thanks !

Comment: By the way, I have not find `texstudio.ini` in my system.

Comment: I installed totpages.sty manually, but then another pkg was missing, it seems that my tex distribution is not installed properly...

Comment: and even when I put the `.sty file `in the `~/texmf ` folder, it cannot recognize it, only put it into the tex file can work

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, first in ubuntu, with a narrowed down window of texstudio, the options would not show up, you have to expand the window to full size, then they would show up. Then for `.sty` missing problem, it because that I did not install texlive properly, so I install it again and ensure everything finished, run texstudio again, then missing `.sty` modules and commands will be found, then everything worked.